# Stored Procedure with Multiple Inputs for One Parameter

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GISQC_UpdAssignUserWork] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@user varchar(20),
@ordnum varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
UPDATE qc_Orders
SET [userName] = @user
WHERE [Ordnum] = @ordnum
```

END

The @ordnum parameter can have multiple values. Is there a way to execute the sp once and have multiple rows update based on the @ordnum parameter?

My VB code:

```
Dim user As String = Me.listUser.SelectedItem.ToString

Dim connstring As String = "Data Source=DVHQSQL01;Initial Catalog=GISQC_ProdCopy;Integrated Security=True"
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connstring)
conn.Open()

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.gridWork.SelectedRows
    'set up SQL command
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("dbo.GISQC_UpdAssignUserWork", conn)
    Dim i As Integer = Me.gridWork.CurrentRow.Index
    Dim ordnum As String = Me.gridWork.Item(0, i).ToString
    With cmd
        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        .Connection = conn
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ordnum", ordnum)
    End With
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Work assigned to user " & user & ".")
Next
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to set the UserName field of more that one record in the qc_orders table? And these records have different OrdNUm?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.gridWork.SelectedRows
        Dim ordnum As String = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString
        'set up SQL command
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("dbo.GISQC_UpdAssignUserWork", conn)

        With cmd
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .Connection = conn
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ordnum", ordnum)
        End With
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Work assigned to user " & user & " ordernum: " & ordnum & ".")
    Next
```

Calling the cell data for each selected row allows for multiple ordnum inputs!